# Photoshop - Generate Image Assets outputting wrong filename?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, generate-image-assets

I'm using the latest version of Photoshop (currently 17.1.1) on OSX 10.11.6 but it's exhibiting some very strange behaviour.

I have a series of images that are variants of another set of PSDs. I used "Save As..." to duplicate the originals with a new filename. I have made the changes to the new files I needed to, but then something exceptionally strange happens when I enable

`Generate > Image Assets`

It's generating a JPG image of the PSD file **with the OLD filename**!

So let's say I have a PSD called `FirstImage.psd`. I open it in Photoshop, use "Save As..." to save it as `SecondImage.psd`. Now I open `SecondImage.psd` and then enable `Generate > Image Assets`. It then *automatically* generates:

> SecondImage.psd-assets/**FirstImage.jpg**

Which is a image of what the whole file looks like. There are no layers or groups telling it to do that.

I'm completely baffled. I have no layers or groups anywhere called `"FirstImage.jpg80%"`. I've even tried quitting out of Photoshop and going back in. It always generates the filename from the previous name of the document before "Save As...".

Any ideas?

Comment: To generate assets you have to manually name the layers. Are you saying that the assets are being renamed to the .psd name verses the name of the layer?

Or are you saying that the assets being generated are being put into the old .psd's asset folder?

Comment: I am saying neither of those things. Please read the question carefully, it is VERY strange. I think it might even be a bug.

Comment: I read the question but I don't understand how this is even possible. You have to MANUALLY add a .whatever_file_extension to a layer so it will no matter what use that layer name.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Hence my confusion. I've not come across this before. I assume it's a new feature...?

Comment: Is the Photoshop version you are using CC 2017? I've tested this on CC 2015 and 2016 so far and I can't replicate the issue.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Yes, 17.1.1 as stated in the question.